# Applying group convolutions where each group is constrained to have the same weights

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

Group convolution is available in Keras using code here for example: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/34024#issuecomment-552034933

However, for my specific application, I require that during training, each of the groups in the group convolution has the same weights.  For example, if I have a tensor of shape 8x8x32 and I want to have `groups = 2` and filter_size=3x3, then normal group convolution will use two 3x3x16 tensors to convolve across the first half of the 8x8x32 and the second half of the 8x8x32.  I want to ensure that the two 3x3x16 tensors have the same weights, even during training.

I can do this by getting rid of my group convolution framework and splitting my 8x8x32 tensor into two 8x8x16 tensors, then running each of them through a single non-grouped 3x3x16 convolution.  However, by not using a group convolution framework, the code runs slower because the tasks are not run in parallel.

How can I use the speed upgrade that group convolution offers in Keras while constraining the weights in each group to be the same?

Comment: Looking at the code that you link, it seems it is actually using a single filter, not one per group? There is only one kernel and bias, which would do what you want (all groups use the same convolution parameters). Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: @jdehesa Now that I'm looking closer, I think that you're right. If you put up some code to test it and show that this is true, I'll give you the green check mark

Comment: Umh, no, wait, actually I think you were right... I cannot properly testing, since I don't have TF 2.x configured with GPU, and group convolution doesn't work on CPU. But I can test the shapes using graph mode. It seems that using a filter with shape `(h, w, c1, c2)` on an image with `c` channels gives you a result with `c2` channels, where `c2` ust be a multiple of `c / c1`, and not `c2 * (c / c1)`, as I was expecting. Which I guess means that actually different filters are used for each group. But should be easy to work around with tiling.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, how group convolutions work in TensorFlow (at the moment, at least, since it does not seem to be documented yet, so I guess it could change) is, given a batch `img` with shape `(n, h, w, c)` and a filter `k` with shape `(kh, kw, c1, c2)`, it makes a convolution in `g = c / c1` groups where the result has `c2` channels. `c` must be divisible by `c1` and `c2` must be a multiple of `g`. As I understand it, this means that, if we call the number of output channels per group `a = c2 / g`, then the first group uses the filters `k[:, :, :, :a]`, the second group `k[:, :, :, a:2*a]`, and so on. If you want to use exactly the same filters for every convolution group, you just need to make filters for a single group, with shape `(kh, kw, c1, a)` and then tile it `g` times in the last dimension.

In the code that you reference, you would just need to make the following changes. The definition of `self.kernel` would change to:

```py
# Make sure self.filters is divisible by self.groups
kernel_shape = self.kernel_size + (input_dim // self.groups, self.filters // self.groups)
# Filters for a single group
self.kernel_base = self.add_weight(
    name='kernel',
    shape=kernel_shape,
    initializer=self.kernel_initializer,
    regularizer=self.kernel_regularizer,
    constraint=self.kernel_constraint,
    trainable=True,
    dtype=self.dtype)
# Tile filters for the rest of groups
self.kernel = tf.tile(self.kernel_base, [1, 1, 1, self.groups])
```

Assuming you also want the bias to work in the same way, you would do the same with it:

```py
if self.use_bias:
    # Bias for a single group
    self.bias_base = self.add_weight(
        name='bias',
        shape=(self.filters // self.groups,),
        initializer=self.bias_initializer,
        regularizer=self.bias_regularizer,
        constraint=self.bias_constraint,
        trainable=True,
        dtype=self.dtype)
    # Bias for all groups
    self.bias = tf.tile(self.kernel_base, [1, 1, 1, self.groups])
else:
    self.bias = None
```

The rest of the code would work similarly, as [`tf.nn.conv2d`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/conv2d) would just use `self.kernels` as before, and `self.bias` would be added similarly.

Comment: this will initialize them to be the same, but during training they will diverge yes?

Comment: @PaulTerwilliger there is only one set of weights that can be updated, ```kernel_base```, which is tiled for each group. Updating ```kernel_base``` will update the weights for all the groups so they will be the same throughout training.

Comment: @PaulTerwilliger As iyop45 says, there is only one set of weights, it gets replicated. The changes are applied to the single set of filters, and on the next step those are replicated again.

Comment: I understand that this works: `import numpy as np`, `foo=np.arange(3)`, `bar=[foo, foo]` because if i do `foo[2] += 5` bar will change as well.  but if i do `baz=np.tile(foo, 2)` then `foo[2]+=5` doesn't change baz, and `baz[2] += 5` does not change `baz[5]`.  this is because `np.tile` creates a copy, and i'm concerned that `tf.tile` also creates a copy and will not keep the constraint

Comment: @jdehesa if you can show that `tf.tile` propogates changes from one group to another to keep the constraint, i'll give you the green check mark. i'm just concerned that it won't do that.

Answer (score 0):

### New answer

Ah, I though you wanted to be assured that the standard grouped convolution used the same weights for both groups. Yes it does!!!

The difference between what you want and what tensorflow does is that you want to "contatenate" results of two groups while tensorflow probably "sums" the results of the two groups.

In this case, you can try to use a `TimeDistributed` convolution. I'm not sure if the performance is different from simply splitting the data in two as you wanted, but you will use a single layer and that might bring you a performance advantage:

```
inputs = Input((8,8,32))
grouped = Reshape((8,8,2,16))(inputs)
grouped = Permute((3,1,2,4))(grouped) #this might be a performance drawback
conv_out = TimeDistributed(Conv2D(half_filters, (3,3), ...))(grouped)
ungrouped = Permute((2,3,1,4))(conv_out)
ungrouped = Reshape((x,y,2*half_filters))
```

---

### Old answer

If you calculate the shape of the weights with the following code from your source:

```
kernel_shape = self.kernel_size + (input_dim // self.groups, self.filters)
```

The result, according to your example will be:

```
(3, 3, 32//2, filters)
```

This does support the idea that is only one half-size kernel for the two groups. There is only half the number of parameters.

You can check this with a simple model:

```
inputs = Input((x, y, channels))
outputs1 = Conv2D(filters, 3, padding="same")(inputs)
outputs2 = GroupConv2D(filts, 2, groups=2, padding="same")(inputs)

model1 = Model(inputs, outputs1)
model2 = Model(inputs, outputs2)

model1.summary() #count the parameters
model2.summary() #expect half the parameters
```

Comment: if the kernel is a group convolution where groups=2 with my constraint, it should be a quarter of the parameters.  This is because the input filter count is halved AND the output filter count is halved for the kernel.  If the parameter count is halved, that's how normal group convolutions work, and it's not evidence that it has my constraint

Comment: @PaulTerwilliger,  Answer updated with a suggestion. You could have explained it better in your question. Tensorflow "does" use the same kernel for both groups. The difference is that you want a different grouping operation. You want to concatenate two results while tensorflow sums the two groups at the end. That doesn't mean that tensorflow doesn't use the same kernel for both groups. It does.

Comment: does tensorflow sum the two groups?  i thought it concatenates them in the example i gave.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the tf.tile solution that @jdehesa wrote is your best choice.

However if you happen to have your data formatted in channel_first/NCHW format you could also try to reshape from (n, g * c, h, w) to (n * g, c, h, w) before the convolution and then reshape back after the convolution.